# Carregar variável com Expressões lambdas percorrendo uma lista

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

Primeiramente fiz esse código:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vlstAcessos.Count - 1; i++)
                        {
                            if (vlstAcessos[i].DsURLTransacao == "frmANAAguardeProcesso.aspx")
                                transacaoANA = vlstAcessos[i].DsURLTransacao = "frmANAAguardeProcesso.aspx";
                            else if (vlstAcessos[i].DsURLTransacao == "frmPVListaProcessos.aspx")
                                transacaoPV = vlstAcessos[i].DsURLTransacao = "frmPVListaProcessos.aspx";
                            else if (vlstAcessos[i].DsURLTransacao == "frmGESStatusPriorizar.aspx")
                                transacaoGestor = vlstAcessos[i].DsURLTransacao = "frmGESStatusPriorizar.aspx";
                            else if (vlstAcessos[i].DsURLTransacao == "frmConsultarProcessos.aspx")
                                transacaoConsulta = vlstAcessos[i].DsURLTransacao = "frmConsultarProcessos.aspx";
                        }
```

Depois vi que esse código está feio e fiz esse:

```
transacaoPV = vlstAcessos.Any(l => l.DsURLTransacao == "frmPVListaProcessos.aspx").ToString();
```

Sei perfeitamente que a expressão lambda acima retornará um True ou False. A pergunta é: Tem como com uma Lambda eu carregar uma variável string com o valor da expressão? Ou seja, `transacaoPV` ficar com o valor de: `frmPVListaProcessos.aspx`
Essas lambdas substitui o IF acima, certo?

```
transacaoGestor   = vlstAcessos.Select(l => l.DsURLTransacao).FirstOrDefault(d => d == "frmGESStatusPriorizar.aspx");
                        transacaoPV       = vlstAcessos.Select(l => l.DsURLTransacao).FirstOrDefault(d => d == "frmPVListaProcessos.aspx");
                        transacaoANA      = vlstAcessos.Select(l => l.DsURLTransacao).FirstOrDefault(d => d == "frmANAAguardeProcesso.aspx");
                        transacaoConsulta = vlstAcessos.Select(l => l.DsURLTransacao).FirstOrDefault(d => d == "frmConsultarProcessos.aspx");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pra ser bem breve, você poderia substituir

```
transacaoPV = vlstAcessos.Any(l => l.DsURLTransacao == "frmPVListaProcessos.aspx").ToString();
```

por isso aqui:

```
transacaoPV = vlstAcessos.Select(l => l.DsURLTransacao)
                         .FirstOrDefault(d=> d == "frmPVListaProcessos.aspx");
```

Um adendo é que o `default` da string (e de qualquer outra classe não-primitiva) é null, então a variável `transacaoPV` ficará nula se não encontrar a string em questão.

OBS: Acabei de olhar o texto do título da pergunta e embora eu tenha entendido o que você quis dizer, está um tanto confuso.

Comment: Vou editar. Em realidade deveria estar dentro do corpo o título.

Comment: posso então afirmar que posso substiituir o if anterior por essas lambdas, certo? Fica um código mais limpo.